# Звук в гостевой ОС: qemu-kvm + virt-manager + alsa

Tags: qemu, alsa

На дворе 2020 год, и я в очередной раз попытался завести в qemu-kvm гостя со звуком. В очередной раз у меня них..чего не получилось.

На борту:

- Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) (Linux 4.19.0-6-amd64);
- QEMU emulator version 3.1.0;
- virt-manager 2.2.1;
- alsa-base 1.0.27+1, alsa-utils 1.1.8-2.

Создал две виртуалки: Win7 и WinXP. Конфигурации одинаковые за исключением звука: в Win7 поставил HDA (ICH9), в WinXP поставил AC97. Дрова в обеих ОС успешно установились. При воспроизведении звукового файла в гостевой ОС микшер показывает изменение уровня звука, а значит файл воспроизводится корректно.

В гугле меня не банили, потому перешерстил все новые темы, но рекомендации не изменились:

- правка /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf:

```
  vnc_allow_host_audio = 1
  nographics_allow_host_audio = 1
  user = "username"
  group = "username"
```

- правка /usr/bin/kvm:

```
  #! /bin/sh
  export QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=alsa
  exec qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm "$@"
```

- правка xml машины:

```
  <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
```

Звука как не было, так и нет. Если у кого есть подвижки в этом направлении, буду очень благодарен за информацию.

P.S.: Не хочу никого обижать, но если это не возможно, так и напишите (и я пойду полный разочарования опять ставить vbox), поэтому любителям комментариев ради комментариев [посвящается](https://pikabu.ru/story/osobennosti_natsionalnyikh_forumov_5767109).

Answer (score 0):

Обновился из SID и вернул все конфиги в дефолт. Звук в обоих гостях завёлся без шаманства.

Версии системы и пакетов:
- Debian GNU/Linux bullseye/sid (Linux 5.4.0-2-amd64);
- QEMU emulator version 4.2.0 (Debian 1:4.2-1);
- virt-manager 2.2.1;
- alsa-base 1.0.27+1, alsa-utils 1.1.9-1.